# Anonymous Type from LINQ but I need Array

Tags: vb.net, linq, anonymous-types

I have a LINQ code to extract values from a data table.

```
 Dim dWYLDs = (From myrow In oSubData 
 Where mySubbasins.Contains(myrow("Subbasin"))
 Group By xs = Val(myrow("X"))
 Into myTotal = Sum(Val(myrow("WYLD")))).ToArray
```

I want to get a sing array of **WYLD** (as double). Instead, on inspection of the rows

(`using .GetType method`), I have...

```
VB$AnonymousType_1`2[System.Double,System.Double]
```

How can I cast this to an array? Is something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how to get what you need with the Into clause you have, but something along the lines of:-

```
 Dim dWYLDs = (From myrow In oSubData 
 Where mySubbasins.Contains(myrow("Subbasin"))
 Group By xs = Val(myrow("X"))
 Select CType (Sum(Val(myrow("WYLD"))), Double)).ToArray
```

might provide at least a starting point.

Comment: Thanks,

This is what worked in the end.

> Dim dWYLDs = (From myrow In oSubData Where mySubbasins.Contains(myrow("Subbasin")) Group By xs = Val(myrow("X")) Into myTotal = Sum(Val(myrow("WYLD"))) Select CType(myTotal, Double)).toarray